# How to search for a string other than specify in array count values function?

Tags: php, laravel, function, multidimensional-array, count

I'm trying to create a chart using Chart.js, however, there is a problem when trying to count values from an array. There is a key in array called `reference` with values of `Facebook`, `Google`, `Invitation`, `[Other than all that]`.

```
array_count_values(array_filter(array_column(($participants->toArray()), 'reference')))['Facebook'] ?? '0';
array_count_values(array_filter(array_column(($participants->toArray()), 'reference')))['Google'] ?? '0';
array_count_values(array_filter(array_column(($participants->toArray()), 'reference')))['Invitation'] ?? '0';
array_count_values(array_filter(array_column(($participants->toArray()), 'reference')))['Other'] ?? '0';
```

I want the last line which is looking for other string. Other should be a string that is **other than Facebook, Google and Invitation**. However, if there is any other cleaner/proper way of doing it would also be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be cleaner and more efficient:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_filter(array_column(($participants->toArray()), 'reference')));
$facebook = $counts['Facebook'] ?? 0;
$google = $counts['Google'] ?? 0;
$invitation = $counts['Invitation'] ?? 0;
$others = array_sum($counts) - $facebook - $google - $invitation;
```

Comment: @HaziqAsyraff sorry - forgot the null coalescing. See my edit.

Comment: Perfect! It's working perfectly! Accepted the answer.